How to check if file is added or in edit mode/checked out?
I'm looking for the commands for these things:
Does file exist in depo? And if so is it checked out?
Is local file added?
Thanks!
(extra info)
I've figured out the commands for add and edit, but I want to check the state first before i run these:
p4.run_add("C:\myfile.txt")
p4.run("edit", "//depot/myfile.txt")

the logic would be:
if file exists in depo and is not checked out:
   check out file
else:
   if file is not added:
      add file


To achieve this you could use fstat.
Check that file exist:
fstat_result =p4.run("fstat","//depot/myfile.txt")
if fstat_result and "otherOpen" not in fstat_result[0]:
    p4.run("edit","//depot/myfile.txt")

Check that local file added:
fstat_result =p4.run("fstat","C:\myfile.txt")
if not fstat_result:
    p4.run_add("C:\\myfile.txt")


Thank you kindly! I don't have reputation to upvote yet, but will come back and do when I can!

result = p4.run_fstat("//depot/myfile.txt")

if result:
    # File exists in depot
    if 'action' in result[0] and result[0]['action'] == 'edit':
        print("File is already checked out.")
    else:
        # File exists but is not checked out
        print("Checking out file...")
        p4.run("edit", "//depot/myfile.txt")
else:
    # File does not exist or is not added locally
    print("Adding file to the depot...")
    p4.run_add("C:/myfile.txt")

